# Ошибка доступа к логам сервера

Tags: windows-server

Здравствуйте господа админы!

Подскажите пожалуйста, может, кто сталкивался с проблемой:

> event viewer cannot open the event log or custom view. verify that event log service is running or query too long. Access is dinied (5)

Проблема возникает лишь при попытке открыть некоторые логи ветви `Appplications and Services Logs - Microsoft - Windows`. Например, `Hyper-V-Config\Admin` выдает ошибку, в то же время `Hyper-V-Config\Operational` по-прежнему работает. И так с несколькими из них.

Что было сделано:

1. Проверил права на папку с логами %SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs
2. Проверил права на сами файлы, все файлы есть в наличии, с помощью блокнота открываются отлично, а вот EventViewer не хочет их открывать никак
3. Проверил ветви реестра, как было сказано на сайте Microsoft, там так же права верные

Куда дальше копать, я пока не знаю. Подскажите, может, есть еще идеи?

Answer (score 1):

что-то блокирует запросы, как я понимаю. Может, стоит вручную создать su и попробовать все открыть как хочется? Или, действительно, лог толстоват по размеру, тогда стоит его разбить на несколько частей и смотреть как xml

Comment: Файлы все небольшие. Не силен в аббревиатурах, что вы имеете ввиду под "su"?